# Listview Loading crashing in android when loadind

Tags: android

My doubt is there any way to prevent the some time crashing problem. Actually my android app activity has listview and i have added header and footer view, and activity has also sliding menu fragment. Problem is that some time when my activity loading data from server
it becomes crashing some time.  I have added the error log below

```
11-07 10:03:47.230: E/AndroidRuntime(12104): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.
Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, 
but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() 
when its content changes. [in ListView(2131034201, class android.widget.ListView) 
with Adapter(class com.pmg.hpprotrain.MenuFragment$CustomAdapter)]
```

Comment: You should place your code inside a try-catch block.

Comment: `The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification` Paste in Google

Answer (score 1):

I think you modify your listview from background thread. If you use AsyncTask for retrive data from server. then modify your listview from onPostExecute method.

private class DownloadMp3Task extends AsyncTask {

```
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
      //Yet to code
     }
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     //Yet to code
     }
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //Yet to code
     }
protected void onPreExecute() {
     //Yet to code
     }
}
```

Comment: Great! Also I want to add, please make sure you use your right `Class` context and not an object of that `Class` itself. For example if I have class `MyActivity` it should not be kept in the variable `MyActivity parent` but it should be declared like `Context parent` . Hope no one else faces this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the main UI thread. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan for giving response. I am doing like that what you wrote. My application working , but some times crashing. Actually I have added header view and footer view in listview. I am attaching the image of my screen, If you have any idea please reply me.

Comment: you didn't attach image. Anyway I'm assuming the situation, and i think you can get rid out of this just using the a sync task. As you are working in the main thread, which sometimes crash your application. Please use a separate thread. In case if it does not work, then post your code here or log-cat. I'll solve it for you.

Comment: also if my answer were useful for you, then please accept it. Thanks